# Ember template pre compile performance

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to understand the performance implications of using handlebars templates in a script tag versus precompiling the templates and serving up the JavaScript.

- I assume Ember caches the template once it first compiles in on the client side, right? Doesn't this mean the perf hit is just a one time performance hit.
- What is that performance hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Ember caches the template once it is compiled.

However, [precompiling handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) templates definitely improves the app performance, because it removes an unnecessary step to be done at the browser. This improvement is related to the number of templates in your app.

A benchmark is available [here](http://jsperf.com/definitive-handlebars-precompilation-benchmark).

If you are using broccoli, you can use [broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler](https://github.com/toranb/broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler) to do the job.

Comment: I'm actually running on ASP.Net. Found some good extensions to help either attach all templates to the html as script tags or precompile and serve as JS. Anyways, thanks!